# How to respond to "solve this equation" in a basic algebra class

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

<strike>If it's acceptable practice on math.se, I'd like to really only ask this question of math educators as opposed to students or mathematical researchers.  Some researchers will undoubtedly think the whole question is not worthy of consideration, and some students will not understand the issue. But if you really have something to contribute, please do.</strike>

Imagine yourself teaching a basic algebra class: maybe to grade schoolers or to high schoolers, or in my case, to adults ages 18 and up in a community college. You will encounter "problems" like the following, where for now I am intentionally leaving out words:

$$2x+3=6-x$$

The "answer" to a question like this somehow communicates that $1$ is the only solution, that $x$ needs to equal $1$, that the solution set is $\{1\}$, or $\{x\mid x=1\}$, etc.

Some of my colleagues feel that if the task was to "solve this equation", that "$x=1$" is not an acceptable final response from a student. They say that "$x=1$" is an "equivalent equation" to the original equation, because it has the same solution set. They say that to "solve this equation", to the exclusion of other ways a student might respond, is to write a *set* as part of an English statement. They are happy with: "The solution is $1$", "The solution set is $\{1\}$", or "The solution set is $\{x\mid x=1\}$". But they are emphatic that "$x=1$" or "The solution to the equation is that $x=1$" cannot count as appropriate responses. Answers like these don't get full credit on their exams.

This matters because we are creating a library of higher quality online problems (for WeBWorK) and we need to set a standard for how the solutions should be entered. I am opposed to having answer blanks where the student merely enters a number. So for example I am opposed to having something like "The solution is *_*_." appear on screen and the student only fills in the number. This trains the student that those words don't matter; they don't have to write them and they won't generally pay them any attention. We *could* program the question to understand a whole sentence, but there are too many issues with alternatively worded correct sentences, not to mention poor spelling. Remember, these responses are to be automatically evaluated.

I support making the students have to enter "$x=1$", because it is a whole statement. And if they enter something simpler, like "$1$", it is an easy matter to shoot back an automated message that their response is not the form we are looking for. And I counter the idea that "$x=1$" has to be interpreted as an "equivalent equation" by saying that sometimes "$x=1$" is an *assertion* (aka an *assignment*) rather than an equation to solve; I'm asserting that $x$ has to equal $1$ for the equation to be true.

So my question to this community, assuming you support my position, is: can you help me make better arguments for my case? I suppose to stay within math.se guidelines, I will say that I am open to being just plain wrong, and definitive mathematical vocabulary expertise can be used to prove it.

Comment: A brief comment not on your question, but on your opening disclaimer: I don't think your declaration that you "only ask...of math educators as opposed to students or mathematical researchers" is helpful or constructive. A big part of Math.SE and MO is that mathematicians, despite all their differences, comprise one community, and it is that unity which makes the sites so powerful. And as a side note, I'd have a hard time finding a mathematical researcher (especially one active here) who is not also an educator.

Comment: Also a comment on the question itself: what would your opponents in this dispute require as an answer to the question "Find the solution to 5x+3y=2,2x-y=1"?

Comment: I think you can have it one way or the other but not both: either automated grading or grading based on ability to communicate mathematically. I also disagree with your colleagues: formalities like solution sets only make sense given a formal treatment of polynomials, which I don't think you're likely to be dealing with in that context. Note: I'm a mere student.

Comment: If I were asked to solve that equation, my answer would be "$x=1$".  It is, indeed, as your colleagues claim, a statement equivalent to the given equation. And that's what I mean by "solving" an equation: Find an equivalent statement that *explicitly* tells what the values of the unknowns are.

Comment: Caveat: I'm extremely skeptical of the value of WebWork (although it is the best such system I have personally encountered). If the teacher can't see what mistakes the student is making, how can zie get to their root cause? The only place I can see such a system being useful is for periodic review: a few exercises from the previous few chapters each week might help solidify things.

Comment: @bgammage point take about the disclaimer. I needlessly feared a barrage of "who cares?" and votes to close as not constructive. To your question, these colleagues would want $(5/11,-1/11)$. Change $x$ and $y$ to some other letters and I have no idea.

Comment: @dfeuer Online homework should never completely replace other homework. But an intelligent system like WeBWorK can  give pretty decent feedback immediately instead of after a week. And if wrong, the student is free to keep at it rather than have a permanent poor mark. Also, this is the _only_ way to hold students accountable for the appropriate number of exercises when you don't have TA's or something to properly grade it all.

Comment: In defense of your colleagues (not that I agree with them), I think they are trying to avoid the student confusing this use of $x$ to mean "the secret number that makes the equality true" and the later use of $x$ as "independent variable of a function". By requiring students to speak about solution sets, they are hoping the student will think "I know $x$ can take on any real number, but the set of $x$-values for which this particular equality is true is $\{1\}$." As others have said, early algebra is a poor time for this sort of subtlety.

Comment: alex.jordan, point taken, especially using WebWork in interactive/try-try-again mode. As a teacher, I'd be tempted to be sneaky about it—give credit for spending time working on it rather than the number of correct answers, but let the students think otherwise.

Comment: May I suggest you ask this question on the UX site - this is really not fundamentally a mathematical question and their expertise is likely more relevant.  And I should add I'm fairly confident they will suggest you accept an answer in any reasonable format - you are making distinctions much finer than those in the student's mental model and pedagogically this is not the appropriate time to throw more advanced concepts at them than what they are focusing on trying to learn.  It's a little disconcerting that this isn't more apparent to all of you, though you seem ahead of your colleagues.

Comment: @psr I think it is fundamentally a math education question, not a user experience question. This isn't _really_ about entering answers online; the same colleagues of mine treat these answers the same way with pencil-and-paper submissions.

Comment: @alex.jordan - UX isn't about being online either.  Math education is about the experience of the students.  The problem here isn't primarily about technical mathematical issues, it's about how to present math to students.  I believe their expertise is useful and needed.

Comment: To me, it's dead simple. The question I ask is: "Does x equal 1 or doesn't it?" If you reject "x = 1" as an answer, you are saying that x doesn't equal 1, which is plainly wrong.

Comment: Given that in every mathematics class I've ever taken, the teacher/professor would solve the equation one step at a time until ending with something like `x=1` and not going to the next step of writing anything like "The solution is 1", I would assume that either A) the answer is `x=1` or B) it is such a trivial jump from that to the answer that it's not worth the effort of writing it out.  Also, the point of the educator is more about teaching *how*, so you should be grading on the work shown more than the answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 119):

To put it bluntly, those of your colleagues who don’t accept ‘$x=1$’ as a solution don’t speak English. That sort of hyperpedantry accomplishes nothing beyond making students think that mathematics is all about invoking the right (incomprehensible) magic formula(s). I’ll go so far as to say that I think it excessive pedantry to object to $x=\frac12\left(1\pm\sqrt5\right)$ as an answer to a question asking for the solution(s) to $x^2-x-1=0$.

It would be another matter if the question were written *The solution set is* __: that question clearly calls for a set. In that case, however, the script should accept $\{1\}$, $\{x\in\Bbb R:x=1\}$, $\{x:x=1\}$, $[1,1]$, and any other reasonably straightforward variant, but **not** $x=1$, $1$, or the like.

Comment: +1 for "[Pedantry] accomplishes nothing beyond making students think that mathematics is all about invoking the right (incomprehensible) magic formula(s)."

Comment: Agreed. It falls on deaf ears when I point out that this distinction between "equivalent equations" and solutions to equations is something that didn't even occur to them until years after they had earned higher level degrees. Why do some try to teach the highest degrees of subtlety to entry-level students? When do they forget that they became expert mathematicians and didn't learn all that subtlety until long after they themselves had started out?

Comment: I agree.  I think this kind of excessive nitpicking detracts and discourages far far more than it helps, and is part of the reason students struggle so much with mathematics early on.  Instructors at my previous university did this kind of thing all the time and it irritated the hell out of me.  The students don't even understand _how to solve the equation_ let alone how the answer should be expressed to be "pedantically correct."  Who comes up with this %&@#$??

Comment: In my experience, the types of individuals who insist on this type of semantic minutiae are individuals who try to make themselves feel smarter by distancing themselves from the "mean" through pedantry, rather than through accomplishment.

Comment: @Arkamis: Sometimes it’s a misguided attempt to be sure of doing no harm or an exaggerated case of *put their feet on the right track now, and maybe they’ll stay there*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Perhaps, but I find it remarkable that any maths educator would have no acquaintance with, say, an engineer, an accountant, an actuary, or any other professional who uses math every day, who could emphasize that "$x=1$" bears no practical ambiguity. Writing math down is, after all, entirely about communication. And if they do not have such an acquaintance, I worry about the quality of the education the students receive... how could this instructor possibly impress on them the utility of such knowledge when s/he has no first-hand knowledge of it him/herself?

Comment: @Arkamis: Having an acquaintance with an engineer (or whatever) by no means guarantees having any understanding of how the engineer (or whatever) uses or talks about mathematics. (For that matter, the engineer may have gone into engineering because he saw it as a relatively smooth route to management, not because he was all that much interested in engineering; I’ve taught more than a few of those.) Some math majors planning to go into secondary education are very good, and most have good intentions, but in general I don’t expect a great deal on the mathematical side.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You don't expect much from your math students? Why is that? Also, you won't win any points from mathematicians with that form of pedantry—only from pedants. Pedantry does have its place, mostly in that field the mathematicians share with the philosophers and the _____ians, but elementary algebra is not that place.

Comment: @dfeuer: I did not say that. I always pushed them hard — much harder than most of the wanted to be pushed — but the fact remains that a great many of them are not all that strong mathematically, and anyone who expects otherwise is doomed to disappointment. Your comments on pedantry seem a bit superfluous.

Comment: Brian M. Scott's comments so closely echo my own that I doubt I can improve on them. However, as I've often posted about this sort of thing in the past 15 years, I did a google search for "overly pedantic" (a phrase I recall using at least once) and my name to see what I could find, and I found an [18 September 2009 post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6847208) that ends with the following remarks. These remarks pertain to a different situation, but I think readers here can easily make the mental word changes needed so that it speaks to the present situation. **(continued)**

Comment: **(continuation)** *Here's what the writing strikes me as: Authors with a little bit of mathematical background (but not enough to know what mathematics is about or to realize how little they know) who are pleased with themselves for understanding what they view as deep theoretical pure mathematics, and who are eager to tell everyone they can about it, thereby feeding their egos as they show off all the deep material they understand.* **(continued)**

Comment: **(continuation)** *They are also writing for the teacher, not the students, and not doing a very good job at it either, since they pay no attention to helping the reader distinguish between the forest and the trees.*

Comment: I agree that $x = 1$ is a fine response. But given the tone of this thread, I'd like to chime in for the sake of the "pedants." Mathematics (at this level) requires some degree of meticulousness and attention to detail. The ability to distinguish between similar-sounding concepts is important. How many students will tell you that $x^2 -1 = 0$ is a parabola, or that $1$ is a vertical line (in reference to $x = 1$ in the $xy$-plane)?...

Comment: ... I do think that struggling students should focus on technical abilities -- blindly solving an equation is, I think, better than not being able to solve it -- but I also think that average students should be pushed to make these sorts of distinctions. But just as it is difficult for students to get to the level where they can make these kinds of distinctions, I'd say it's similarly difficult (once one is _able_ to be pedantic) to distinguish further between critical distinctions and pedantic ones.

Comment: Your input does indeed help strengthen my case, which is what I sought. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 67):

If they are happy with "The solution set is $\{x\mid x=1\}$", they should also be happy with $\{x\mid 2x+3=6-x\}$" which is equivalent.

If the above $x=1$ answer is not acceptable for some of your collegues, but many students are doing it as I guess it's happening, they should first *think* about what they did wrong: in this case write a question stating clearly that they want the student performing two tasks. Putting the equation in some canonical form with the variable isolated on the left side, secondly states that they know that the result is a set. Outside pedantic mathematic, the second part is irrelevant, and it is disputable that may even be seen as a secondary goal of the exercise.

Which student could believe a corrector is so dumb the corrector may ignore that the result is a set ? If The result is say $x = 11$, should the student also state that he is using base 10 arithmetic ? If the base could possibly be binary it could be ambiguous.

Comment: Your example here does indeed help strengthen my case, which is what I was hoping for. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 20):

A lot of the previous answers seem to have overlooked the importance of making it clear to the user what format the answer needs to be in. If you just have a blank which will accept only "x=1", a lot of students will correctly solve the equation, enter "1" or {1} as their answer, and become very frustrated when the system doesn't accept it. By attempting to force students to enter an answer in a specific (unspecified) format, you are not only engaging in the same sort of "hyperpedantry" you want to avoid, but also causing a lot of unnecessary frustration.

After having tutored a lot of students who had to use this sort of online homework system, it is my belief that the best system is one in which the amount of information that the student has to enter is minimal, to ensure that they get credit for correctly solving the equation. Hence I would recommend the text "x=" followed by a blank, which accepts the answer "1". Perhaps even put reminder text which says something like "enter a single number".

Automated problem checkers are not the best venue for testing pedantic sort of things, e.g. the format of answers (as you describe), whether the student remembers a "+C" in integral calculus, whether the student remembers to include units, etc. They should be used only to assess whether the student can actually solve the problem.

Comment: so true. And if you want to remind students solutions are a set just put brackets in the hardcoded answer form and write the numbers inside it.

Comment: In the past I would agree with your first point. But you may not be familiar with WeBWorK and how fancy it is. Properly written problems are coded so that all these these things are genuinely understood by the software as mathematical objects. You have Davide Cervone to thank for that, the same programmer responsible for MathJax on sites like this.

Comment: For example, in the current version of these problems, "x=1" would be the official answer. If the student types "1" or "{1}", they are told that "they have the right value, but please answer in the form x=__". If they type something incorrect like "2", they are told "please answer in the form x=__". If they type something that is in the wrong ballpark like "x^2" they are told "you are answering with a formula but this problem asks for a solution to an equation." Of course, we could make it so "x=1", "1", "{1}", "{x|x=1}" are all truly understood and accepted, and that is the debate here.

Comment: My philosophy in writing these is to make the experience more truly simulate pencil-and-paper. Extra special instructions about formatting detract from that, and are unnecessary given WeBWorK's feedback system. Also, providing "x = " before an answer blank is not true to the pencil-and-paper experience to my mind either.

Comment: Last comment: WeBWorK handles the "+C" thing with integrals beautifully. If you omit it, or replace it with a specific number, you are told you do not have the most general solution. Even more neat: there's no requirement to use "C". You could add "k", "c", "K", or any symbol for a constant that doesn't already have meaning in the context. And units are handled beautifully too. If you are asked how long is a meter, you can respond "1 m", "100 cm", "39.37 in", etc. If you leave out units, you are told that you have left off units.

Answer (score 3):

This question reminds me of how I could be given the exact same word problem in Grade 2 and again in Grade 7.  The difference in getting the same problem is that what is required to justify my answer is wildly different between these grades.  In Grade 2, it is enough to just work out the number that is the right answer that a teacher accepts without challenge while in Grade 7 the same problem requires stating a variable, formulating an equation and solving it, not unlike what you have as a given problem here.  There is something to be said for **understanding how to justify** an answer which could be a proof, counter-example, or something else to demonstrate an understanding of a concept and its use on some level.

Thus, I'd be tempted to consider what kind of formality are you expecting and would you want to be feeding someone the ideas of how to go through these kinds of problems.  Thus, I'd suggest bringing in Mathematical constructs and setting a bar for what kinds of answers are reasonable.  Otherwise you may run into people that want to claim what may otherwise seem ridiculous.